# How to pass docker run parameter via kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Hi I am running kubernetes cluster where I run Logstash container.

But I need to run it with own docker run parameter. If I would run it in docker directly. I would use command:

```
docker run --log-driver=gelf logstash -f /config-dir/logstash.conf
```

But I need to run it via Kubernetes pod. My pod looks like:

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash-logging
        image: "logstash:latest"
        command: ["logstash", "-f" , "/config-dir/logstash.conf"]
        volumeMounts:
          - name: configs
            mountPath: /config-dir/logstash.conf
```

How to achieve to run Docker container with parameter --log-driver=gelf via kubernetes. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Kubernetes does not expose docker-specific options such as --log-driver. A higher abstraction of logging behavior might be added in the future, but it is not in the current API yet. This issue was discussed in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15478, and the suggestion was to change the default logging driver for docker daemon in the per-node configuration/salt template.